# Shortcut Icon is overlapping with another icon

Tags: windows, virus, icons, shortcuts, desktop-icons

After I download something from the Internet (may have a virus), all of my shortcut file icons are overlapped by a weird icon. The icon looks like the icon of the file without any icon attached to it (See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR5J3.jpg)). This is looking very unpleasant on the eye and looks like my computer has some kind of virus. How can I restore the icon to its original one?

Comment: May have been a virus? You don't know what you downloaded, and, I presume, installed? Look in your list of installed programs and find the one recently installed, and uninstall it.

Comment: Also, please note that viruses don't want to be apparent. They have more value, usually, when they are subtle and remain in the background. While what you observe is very visible, it may be malware, and likely unwanted, but it is probably not actually a virus.

Comment: @music2myear yeah the day I install that thing, a bunch of random apps shown up, and want to install too and well I uninstall all of them.